# Django editing model instance

Tags: python, django

The Django project that I am working on lists patient details and lets the user edit the details. I have been able to list it out but `views.py` is not getting linked to the url for updating the list.

**views.py**:

```
    def update_patient(request, patient_id):
        patient = Patient.objects.get(id=patient_id)
        if request.method != 'POST':
            form = PatientForm(instance=patient)
        else:
            # POST data submitted; process data.
            form = PatientForm(instance=patient, data=request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('patient:patient',
                                            args=[patient.id]))
    context = { 'patient': patient, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'patient/update_patient.html', context)
```

**models.py**:

```
  class Patient(models.Model):
      patientID = models.CharField(max_length=20)
      firstName =models.CharField(max_length=20)
      lastName = models.CharField(max_length=20)
      age = models.IntegerField(max_length=None)
      SSN = models.CharField(max_length=15)
      address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
      date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**urls.py**:

```
url(r'^patients/(?P<patient_id>\update\d+)/$', views.update_patient, name='update'),
```

**update_patient.html**:

```
{% extends "patient/base.html" %} {% block content %}
  <p><a href="{% url 'patient:patient' patient.id %}">{{ patient }}</a>
  </p>
  <p>Update Patient:</p>

  <form action="{% url 'patient:update' patient.id %}" method='post'>
   {% csrf_token %} {{ form.as_p }}
  <button name='submit'>add entry</button>
  </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: try this  url(r'^patients/(?P<patient_id>[0-9]+)/update$', views.update_patient, name='update'),

Comment: Thank you. corrected the url I am not being able to access the updating details in the browser

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Answer (score 0):

Your URL pattern is wrong, you have `\update` within capturing group, it shouldn't be, change the pattern to this:

```
url(r'^patients/(?P<patient_id>\d+)/update/$', views.update_patient, name='update')
```